# ORA-04091 table name is mutating in trigger due to cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, cursor

So when I compile the following script it throws the mutating table error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SEND_MAIL
BEFORE DELETE
ON CATEGORIE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
bodytext  varchar2(100);

CURSOR getabonnee IS
SELECT CATEGORIEABONNEMENT.MAILABONNEEID, NAAM 
FROM CATEGORIE
INNER JOIN CATEGORIEABONNEMENT ON CATEGORIEABONNEMENT.CATEGORIENAAM = CATEGORIE.NAAM
WHERE NAAM = :old.NAAM;

CURSOR getabonneeinfo(p_id CATEGORIEABONNEMENT.MAILABONNEEID%TYPE) IS
SELECT MAILABONNEE.VOORNAAM, MAILABONNEE.ACHTERNAAM, MAILABONNEE.EMAILADRES
FROM CATEGORIEABONNEMENT
INNER JOIN MAILABONNEE ON MAILABONNEE.ID = CATEGORIEABONNEMENT.MAILABONNEEID
WHERE MAILABONNEEID = p_id;

BEGIN

   FOR cc IN getabonnee LOOP

      FOR cc2 IN getabonneeinfo(cc.MAILABONNEEID) LOOP

     bodytext := cc2.voornaam || cc2.achternaam || :old.NAAM;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE bodytext;

     SENDMAILABONNEE(bodytext, cc2.emailadres);

     DELETE FROM CATEGORIEABONNEMENT
     WHERE MAILABONNEEID = cc.MAILABONNEEID;

     UPDATE NIEUWSBERICHT
     SET CATEGORIENAAM = null
     WHERE CATEGORIENAAM = :old.NAAM;

  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
/

savepoint deletecategory;

delete from Categorie where naam='Buitenland';

rollback to deletecategory;
```

I looked for solutions to this error and found that people suggest using a compound trigger. The problem is that for some reason, my database software (Oracle SQL Developer) doesn't recognize the compound trigger as a valid unit. I checked my oracle version and I have 11g so I don't quite understand why it won't work. Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: So, you must be getting some sort of compile error.  PLease be more specific.

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop?  within the trigger your `Delete from Categorie where naam='Buitenland'` from categorie, the trigger is for table categorie before delete. I believe the system will recursively call the trigger before update thus entering an infinite loop.  But my knowledge of triggers is weak.  Just seems like a logic flaw.

Comment: @OldProgrammer when I use a compound trigger it throws error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following: function, pragma, procedure, before, after, etc.      The compile error for the code above is ORA-04091:  table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

Comment: "Oracle SQL Developer" is not your database software -- it is just the interface to the Oracle RDBMS. Possibly the version the RDBMS you are using does not support compound triggers.

Comment: Don't select/update/delete from the same table the trigger is on because it's in a state of change, hence "mutating".

Comment: If NAAM is primary or unique key on CATEGORIE you may be able to get rid of the DELETE on NIEUWSBERICHT by defining a foreign key relating NIEUWSBERICHT.CATEGORIENAAM to CATEGORIE.NAAM and setting it up as ON DELETE SET NULL.

Answer (score 2):

In your first cursor, do not include the CATEGORIE table in the query. The trigger already has the values for all of the columns in the rows you are deleting, so change it to:

```
SELECT MAILABONNEEID 
  FROM CATEGORIEABONNEMENT
 WHERE CATEGORIEABONNEMENT.CATEGORIENAAM = :old.NAAM;
```